# Identify a story where man wins right to pilot first rocketship by disabling Warning Indicators

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for the identity of a short story that taught me a good life lesson.

In this short story from some 30 or so years ago, trainees hoping to pilot the first rocket ship, keep failing the flight simulations and crashing the simulated rocketship. Finally, one candidate realizes there are too many unnecessary gauges and warning indicators distracting the pilots from flying the ship. He immediately starts to disconnect unnecessary gauges, lights, etc., before starting the simulation again.

Thus this candidate wins the right to pilot the first new rocket, not because he was the first to notice the (deliberately?) flawed cockpit design, but because he immediately started to fix it without waiting.

I drew the life lesson that if you notice a problem, where possible you should do something about it, without waiting for someone else to fix it. It is a lesson that serves me well to this day.